# Replacing a field with duplicate info to zero in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
|data| fromDateTime       | toDateTime          |
 ------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 2017-09-08 08:00:00 | 2017-09-08 11:00:00 |
| 2 | 2017-09-08 08:00:00 | 2017-09-08 11:00:00 |
| 2 | 2017-09-08 08:00:00 | 2017-09-08 11:00:00 |
| 3 | 2017-09-08 11:30:00 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 |
| 3 | 2017-09-08 11:30:00 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 |
| 4 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 | 2017-09-08 19:00:00 |
| 4 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 | 2017-09-08 19:00:00 |
| 4 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 | 2017-09-08 19:00:00 |
```

And I need to return this

```
   |data| fromdatetime       | toDateTime          |
     ------------------------------------------------
    | 2 | 2017-09-08 08:00:00 | 2017-09-08 11:00:00 |
    | 0 | 2017-09-08 08:00:00 | 2017-09-08 11:00:00 |
    | 0 | 2017-09-08 08:00:00 | 2017-09-08 11:00:00 |
    | 3 | 2017-09-08 11:30:00 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 |
    | 0 | 2017-09-08 11:30:00 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 |
    | 4 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 | 2017-09-08 19:00:00 |
    | 0 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 | 2017-09-08 19:00:00 |
    | 0 | 2017-09-08 17:00:00 | 2017-09-08 19:00:00 |
```

The moral of the story is that the data in the "data" column contains duplicate information that gets summed in a report resulting in bad info I NEED THAT ROW THOUGH I cannot get rid of the row with distinct. Also there are many other columns that get returned with this query that contain similar but sometimes different information with no primary key associated with it so I need the rows I cannot use distinct

Comment: Add the query to your question, otherwise there's no way to help.

Comment: Show the 14 line query, so we can help. Can't do much without that.

Comment: Also - 14 lines is really only small sized, unless somebody is being terrible about concat-ing lines.  I've had more table references than that in a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql):

```
Select IIF(LAG(data,1, 0) OVER  (ORDER BY data) = data, 0, data) as data
      ,fromDateTime
      ,toDateTime
From @temp;
```

[image]

I hope you are not using version older then SQL Server 2012.